# How to communicate from secornd page to first page usin javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, window.location

I have a requirement where i have to show the selected dropdown option from first page to second page of application.

I have tried to write FirstPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>First page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="abc">
Dropdown:  <select id="ddlViewBy" onchange="fun()">
<option value="1">select</option>
<option value="2">test1</option>
<option value="3">test2</option>
<option value="4">test3</option>
</select>
<p>selected option is :<b id="abc"></b></p>
<button onclick="redirect()">Redirect</button>
</div>
<script>
function fun(){
    var e = document.getElementById("ddlViewBy");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML=strUser;
}
function redirect(){
    var linkToSeconPage="http://localhost:63342/test/SecondPage.html";
    window.location.href=linkToSeconPage;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the SecondPage.html where i need to access **strUser**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>second page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>here i want to access the selected dropdown value from first page</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please throw some light on the approach to use strUser to SecondPage.html.

And also the window.location.href=linkToSeconPage; is not working in firefox.
I have also tried window.location=linkToSeconPage; , window.location.assign(linkToSeconPage); and using return false; after this after searching on google for answer but nothing worked in firefox but everything worked on IE 11.

Could you also suggest alternative for this using in firefox.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could pass it to the second page using a cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location.assign(url)` and `location = url` are [equivalent and supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) in FireFox. Try leaving off `window`.

Appending a value to the querystring as suggested by @Sam is not a bad option. Another option, which can be useful in more complex situations - or when you don't want to expose the selected value in the querystring (the value will be stored in logged files), is to use [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). In first page, add

```
sessionStorage.setItem('SELECTED', strUser);
```

And on page, you can retrieve with

```
sessionStorage.getItem('SELECTED');
```

SessionStorage stores the value in the browser for the lifetime of the user's current session. The token/key (`SELECTED` in my example, but can be any text) is scoped to the domain; thus other websites can't read the data that you place into SessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value to the second page using a get parameter e.g.

```
 window.location.href=linkToSeconPage + '?val=valueToPassThrough';
```

Then on the second page use:

```
var theValue = window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```

However note that this will not take into account other get parameters passed to the page and in this respect it is fragile.

This is a very manual way of doing it and you would probably want to write a function which extracts this exact behaviour for you - and of course checks for problems with `split` - the above code assumes there is a `?` in the URL and the argument required is the first one.